# Accented character in column name MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a problem running a query on my SQL DB.

```
String code = xyz123    
String sql="SELECT a.ACode, b.BCod 
     FROM (b RIGHT JOIN c ON b.BCod = c.CCod) 
          INNER JOIN a ON c.à = a.ID 
     WHERE b.BCod="+code;
System.out.println(sql);
```

This should give me a list of data.
I think the problem is the field with accented character.

> c.à

If i run the same query on phpmyadmin it works fine.

```
SELECT a.ACode, b.BCod FROM (b RIGHT JOIN c ON b.BCod = c.CCod) INNER JOIN a ON c.à = a.ID WHERE b.BCod="xyz123"
```

This is the query i run on phpmyadmin that works fine. 
I need to make that work on Java.

Comment: That is *not* PHP... !?

Comment: That seems to Java or C#

Comment: Well i just clicked on suggested tags, my bad.

Comment: You need to quote non-ascii field names (in MySQL with `\``, so `c.\`à\``)

Answer (score 2):

PHPMyAdmin ticks `` ` `` the names of the tables to allow for strangely named tables. That probably will fix the problem you're having

```
String sql="SELECT a.ACode, b.BCod 
 FROM (b RIGHT JOIN c ON b.BCod = c.CCod) 
      INNER JOIN a ON `c.à` = a.ID 
 WHERE b.CodComm="+code;
```

Comment: I did edit the code of the original message to show you the query i run on phpmyadmin that works fine